# MySQL:How To Select all carts in which All product has been paid

Tags: sql, select

I have two table similar below

If we have shopping cart table as carts is like below

```
id     date     title
---------------------
1      2016       a
2      2015       b
3      2018       c
4      2019       dd
```

And product table is some thing like below

```
id     cart_id    status
--------------------------
1         2        paid
2         2        paid
3         1        paid
4         1        unpaid
5         1        paid
6         3        paid
7         3        paid
```

Expected output (only carts in which All product has been paid) is:

```
cart_id    status
-------------------
   3        paid
   2        paid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group by cart_id` and with a `HAVING` clause apply the condition that there is no `'unpaid'` value in the column `status`:

```
select cart_id, max(status) status
from product
group by cart_id
having sum(status = 'unpaid') = 0
```

I assume that in the column `status` the only possible values are `'paid'` and `'unpaid'`, so instead of `max(status) status` you can use `'paid' status` as the 2nd column.
Or with NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct p.cart_id, p.status
from product p
where not exists (
  select 1 from product
  where cart_id = p.cart_id and status = 'unpaid'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6HUPXoKPNKWxG2EatE3kPN/0).
Results:

```
| cart_id | status |
| ------- | ------ |
| 2       | paid   |
| 3       | paid   |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This adjusted code-

```
SELECT carts.id,'Paid' Status
FROM carts
INNER JOIN product on carts.id = product.cart_id
GROUP BY carts.id
HAVING COUNT(Status) = SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Paid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: I edit table to describe better, I need one and only one row of every cart in result

Comment: @shohrehshiran I have adjusted the code as per the clarified requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This seems the simplest logic:

```
select p.cart_id, p.status
from product p
where p.status = 'paid';
```

Comment: Carts with unpaid products can still be returned. Your query means "select all carts with _at least one_ paid product". OP asked for carts with _all_ products paid.